# How to print assosiative array data

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 7
            [price] => 1300
            [discount] => 13
            [early_bird_date] => 2014-12-30
            [timing] => 
            [batch] => 
            [slug] => 
            [status] => 1
            [ktw_course_id] => 5
            [ktw_country_id] => 2
            [ktw_city_id] => 5
            [ktw_timeslot_id] => 0
            [ktw_training_mode_id] => 3
            [ktw_currency_id] => 6
            [created] => 
            [modified] => 
            [course] => jquery
            [country] => kuwait
            [city] => dubai
            [currency] => EUR
            [workshop_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [start_date] => 2014-11-04
                            [end_date] => 2015-01-05
                            [status] => 1
                            [ktw_workshop_id] => 7
                            [created] => 2014-11-28 06:09:41
                            [modified] => 2014-11-28 06:09:41
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 8
                            [start_date] => 2015-01-06
                            [end_date] => 2015-01-07
                            [status] => 1
                            [ktw_workshop_id] => 7
                            [created] => 2014-11-28 06:09:55
                            [modified] => 2014-11-28 06:09:55
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                            [start_date] => 2015-01-08
                            [end_date] => 2015-01-09
                            [status] => 1
                            [ktw_workshop_id] => 7
                            [created] => 2014-11-28 06:10:15
                            [modified] => 2014-11-28 06:10:15
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 5
            [price] => 900
            [discount] => 13
            [early_bird_date] => 2014-11-26
            [timing] => 
            [batch] => 
            [slug] => 
            [status] => 1
            [ktw_course_id] => 5
            [ktw_country_id] => 1
            [ktw_city_id] => 2
            [ktw_timeslot_id] => 0
            [ktw_training_mode_id] => 1
            [ktw_currency_id] => 1
            [created] => 
            [modified] => 2014-11-14 14:34:29
            [course] => jquery
            [country] => india
            [city] => vizag
            [currency] => INR
            [workshop_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [start_date] => 2014-11-28
                            [end_date] => 2014-11-29
                            [status] => 1
                            [ktw_workshop_id] => 5
                            [created] => 
                            [modified] => 
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 6
            [price] => 1300
            [discount] => 13
            [early_bird_date] => 2014-12-30
            [timing] => 
            [batch] => 
            [slug] => 
            [status] => 1
            [ktw_course_id] => 5
            [ktw_country_id] => 1
            [ktw_city_id] => 4
            [ktw_timeslot_id] => 0
            [ktw_training_mode_id] => 2
            [ktw_currency_id] => 1
            [created] => 
            [modified] => 2014-11-25 10:16:58
            [course] => jquery
            [country] => india
            [city] => hyderabad
            [currency] => INR
            [workshop_dates] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 4
                            [start_date] => 2014-12-30
                            [end_date] => 2014-12-31
                            [status] => 1
                            [ktw_workshop_id] => 6
                            [created] => 2014-11-28 06:08:44
                            [modified] => 2014-11-28 06:08:44
                        )

                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 5
                            [start_date] => 2014-12-31
                            [end_date] => 2015-01-01
                            [status] => 1
                            [ktw_workshop_id] => 6
                            [created] => 2014-11-28 06:08:59
                            [modified] => 2014-11-28 06:08:59
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [start_date] => 2015-01-02
                            [end_date] => 2015-01-03
                            [status] => 1
                            [ktw_workshop_id] => 6
                            [created] => 2014-11-28 06:09:14
                            [modified] => 2014-11-28 06:09:14
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

i want to print start_date and end _date ,please help me how can i get it.
     thanks in advance.

Comment: Those are objects not arrays. How are you generating them?

Comment: $array[2]->workflow_dates->start_date and $array[2]->workflow_dates->end_date?

Comment: @Antony D'Andrea i am sorry

Comment: @Peter here $array[2] means workshop_dates am i rite

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very beginner level question.

```
foreach ($YourVariable as $arr_of_objs ) {
    foreach ($arr_of_objs->workshop_dates as $obj) {
        echo $obj->start_date;
        echo $obj->end_date;
        # code...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the objects are implementing ArrayAccess. You would do:

```
foreach ($object as $obj) {
    foreach($obj[workshop_dates] as $workshopdate) {
        $startDate = $workshopdate ['start_date'];
        $endDate = $workshopdate ['end_date'];
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
$obj = //your object
$newArray = (array)$obj;//converting object to array
foreach ($newArray as $val) {
  foreach ($val['workshop_dates'] as $value) {
    echo $value['start_date']. ' ' .$value['end_date'];
  }
}
```